# matplotlib.lineCollection from pandas dataframe. Slow performance of current iterrows solution

Tags: python, pandas, performance, dataframe, matplotlib

I have a large dataframe which contains coordinates with a value. I want to plot this in matplotlib with a different color for each value.

I have a working solution now that plots this as a lineCollection. I am using iterrows as that is easy to understand for me, but it is very slow.

I merge with another df that contains the color for each value. I then loop through and add to the current segment if the color is same as previous. If not I start a new segment.

```
dff = df.merge(
        df_color,
        how='left',
        left_on='value',
        right_on='value'
    )

segments = []
segments_i = -1
colorlist = []
previous_color = None

for _, row in dff.iterrows():
        point = (row['x'], row['y'])
        color = row['color']

        if np.any(np.isnan(color)):
            color = (0,0,0,0)

        if color == previous_color:
            segments[segments_i].append(point)
            previous_color = color
        else:
            # add endpoint to current segment
            if segments_i > 0:
                segments[segments_i].append(point)

            # start new segment
            segments.append([point])
            colorlist.append(color)

            previous_color = color
            segments_i += 1

colorlist = np.asarray(colorlist)

lc = mc.LineCollection(segments, colors=colorlist)

ax.add_collection(lc)
```

How can I change this to get better performance?

Comment: `.iterrows()` is notoriously slow, and explicit iteration is never the ideal solution in Pandas anyway. We're going to need the entirety of your program, and enough data to benchmark it. Please see: [mcve].

Comment: Yea I read that iterrows() was slow, but thought I needed to use apply() or something similar. I changed out iterrows with 'for x, y in zip(df.x, df.y)' and it is much faster. Still using iteration, but it's fast enough for me now.

Comment: Can you provide enough code and data to reproduce the program? See: [mcve].

Answer (score 1):

I changed this:

```
for _, row in dff.iterrows():
    point = (row['x'], row['y'])
    color = row['color']
```

to this:

```
dff['point'] = list(zip(dff['x'], dff['y']))

for point, color in zip(dff['point'], dff['ctable']):
    ...
```

This small change made it run ~15 times as fast! This is good enough for me for now, but feel free to post if you have a better solution.